# Querying "in" eventAction array in big query

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

I apologize if this has been asked before, but I can't seem to find a specific doc describing how to do this. We are importing our GA data into big query. i simply need to see waht visitors on our site have been viewing two or more pages and completing at least one of a few actions. I am fairly new to BQ, and teh docs I have read talk of using UNNEST, unfortunately, thi sis the issue I am seeing, when i run this query:

```
SELECT visitId, totals.pageviews  FROM `analytics-acquisition-funnel.119485123.ga_sessions_20181009` WHERE totals.pageviews > 2 AND
'modal-click' IN UNNEST(hits.eventInfo.eventAction) 
order by totals.pageviews DESC LIMIT 100000
```

I get the following issue, shouldn't this work. I apologize, I reading this doc, but I feel like my use case is simpler than most shown:
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/arrays#scanning-arrays

Cannot access field eventInfo on a value with type ARRAY> at [2:30]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT visitId, totals.pageviews  
FROM `analytics-acquisition-funnel.119485123.ga_sessions_20181009` 
WHERE totals.pageviews > 2 
AND (SELECT COUNTIF(eventInfo.eventAction = 'modal-click') FROM UNNEST(hits)) > 0 
ORDER BY totals.pageviews DESC 
LIMIT 100000
```

OR

```
#standardSQL
SELECT visitId, totals.pageviews  
FROM `analytics-acquisition-funnel.119485123.ga_sessions_20181009` 
WHERE totals.pageviews > 2 
AND EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM UNNEST(hits) WHERE eventInfo.eventAction = 'modal-click')
ORDER BY totals.pageviews DESC 
LIMIT 100000
```